# References a sub model from parent in typescript using prisma client

Tags: next.js, foreign-keys, prisma

I am learning prisma and I can't figure out how to use the prisma types correctly if the returned data includes a sub model.

For example, I have the following two tables

```
model Services {
    id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    service_name String @db.VarChar(255)
    description String @db.MediumText
    overall_status ServiceStatus @default(OPERATIONAL)
    deleted Boolean @default(false)
    sub_services  SubServices[]
}

model SubServices {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String @db.VarChar(255)
  description String @db.MediumText
  current_status ServiceStatus @default(OPERATIONAL)
  service Services?  @relation(fields: [service_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  service_id  Int?
}
```

I am then pulling data from the Services model using the following:

```
const services = await prisma.services.findMany({
    where: {
        deleted: false
    },
    include: {
        sub_services: true
    }
});
```

I am then in the client side referencing the `Services` model, but the IDE isn't detecting that `Services` can include `sub_services`. I can use it and it works but the IDE is always showing a squiggly line as if the code is wrong, example is below:

```
import {Services} from "@prisma/client";

const MyComponent : React.FC<{service: Services}> = ({services}) => {
    return (
       <>
       service.sub_services.map(service => {
       })
       </>
    )
}
```

but in the above example sub_services is underlined with the error `TS2339: Property 'sub_services' does not exist on type 'Services'.`

So how would I type it in a way that IDE can see that I can access `sub_services` from within `services` model.

**UPDATE**

I found a way to do it, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not as I am creating a new type as below:

```
type ServiceWithSubServices <Services> = Partial<Services> & {
    sub_services: SubServices[]
}
```

and then change the const definition to the below

```
const ServiceParent : React.FC<{service: ServiceWithSubServices<Services>}> = ({service}) => {
```

Although this does seem to work, is this the right way to do it, or is there some more prisma specific that can do it without creating a new type.

Answer (score 0):

In Prisma, by default only the scalar fields are included in the generated type. So, in your case for the `Services` type, all the scalar fields except `sub_services` would be included in the type. `sub_services` is not included because it's a relation field.

To include the relation fields, you would need to use Prisma.validator, here's a [guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-using-variations-of-the-generated-model-type) on generating types that include the relation field.